# FFMPEG - AVFrame to per channel array conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, swscale

I am looking to copy an `AVFrame` into an array where pixels are stored one channel at a time in a row-major order.

Details:

I am using FFMPEG's api to read frames from a video. I have used `avcodec_decode_video2` to fetch each frame as an `AVFrame` as follows:

```
AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx = NULL;
avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, filepath, NULL, NULL);
...
int video_stream_idx;  // stores the stream index for the video
...
AVFrame* vid_frame = NULL;
vid_frame = av_frame_alloc();
AVPacket vid_pckt;
int frame_finish;
...
while (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &vid_pckt) >= 0) {
    if (b_vid_pckt.stream_index == video_stream_idx) {
        avcodec_decode_video2(cdc_ctx, vid_frame, &frame_finish, &vid_pckt);
        if (frame_finish) {
            /* perform conversion */
        }
    }
}
```

The destination array looks like this:

```
unsigned char* frame_arr = new unsigned char [cdc_ctx->width * cdc_ctx->height * 3];
```

I need to copy all of `vid_frame` into `frame_arr`, where the range of pixel values should be [0, 255]. The problem is that the array needs to store the frame in row major order, one channel at a time, i.e. R11, R12, ... R21, R22, ... G11, G12, ... G21, G22, ... B11, B12, ... B21, B22, ... (I have used the notation [color channel][row index][column index], i.e. G21 is the green channel value of pixel at row 2, column 1). I have had a look at `sws_scale`, but I don't understand it enough to figure out whether that function is capable of doing such a conversion. Can somebody help!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you called "one channel at a time" has a term named `planar`. (btw, the opposite format is named `packed`) And almost every pixel format is of row order.

The problem here is the input format may vary and all of them should be converted to one format. That's what `sws_scale()` does.

However, there is no such `planar RGB` format in ffmpeg libs yet. You have to write your own pixel format description into ffmpeg source code `libavutil/pixdesc.c` and re-build the libs.

Or you can just convert the frame into `AV_PIX_FMT_GBRP` format, which is the most similar one to what you want. `AV_PIX_FMT_GBRP` is a planar format, while the green channel is at first and red at last (blue middle). And rearrange these channels then.

```
// Create a SwsContext first:
SwsContext* sws_ctx = sws_getContext(cdc_ctx->width, cdc_ctx->height, cdc_ctx->pix_fmt, cdc_ctx->width, cdc_ctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_GBRP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
// alloc some new space for storing converted frame
AVFrame* gbr_frame = av_frame_alloc();
picture->format = AV_PIX_FMT_GBRP;
picture->width  = cdc_ctx->width;
picture->height = cdc_ctx->height;
av_frame_get_buffer(picture, 32);
....

while (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &vid_pckt) >=0) {
    ret = avcodec_send_packet(cdc_ctx, &vid_pckt);
    // In particular, we don't expect AVERROR(EAGAIN), because we read all
    // decoded frames with avcodec_receive_frame() until done.
    if (ret < 0)
        break;

    ret = avcodec_receive_frame(cdc_ctx, vid_frame);
    if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR(EAGAIN) && ret != AVERROR_EOF)
        break;
    if (ret >= 0) {
        // convert image from native format to planar GBR
        sws_scale(sws_ctx, vid_frame->data, 
                  vid_frame->linesize, 0, vid_frame->height, 
                  gbr_frame->data, gbr_frame->linesize);

        // rearrange gbr channels in gbr_frame as you like
        // g channel is gbr_frame->data[0]
        // b channel is gbr_frame->data[1]
        // r channel is gbr_frame->data[2]
        // ......
    }
}

av_frame_free(gbr_frame);
av_frame_free(vid_frame);
sws_freeContext(sws_ctx);
avformat_free_context(fmt_ctx)
```

Comment: Thanks @halfelf. I did some initial tests and it seems like using sws_scale to convert to GBR is quite slow as compared to just copying pixel by pixel. I will report back!